# What is the correct format to use in PHP when denoting "money" attribute fetched from MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, number-formatting, money-format

I'm using the "number_format" function to denote **money**" attribute in PHP/MySQL.

The attribute itself is stored in my database.

```
  Select account_balance from my_table where login = 'xxxxxx';
  $correct_account_balance = number_format($account_balance,
  ['my_balance'],2);  }
```

In other words :  the denotation "**2**" will add two extra numbers after the decimal point, as follows :   **10.00**  (for example)

This code works fine............except for one small problem :  if the amount after the decimal point has a zero at the end, it does not display!

For example :  if the amount is, say,  **10 dollars and 35 cents**,  it displays correctly :   **10.35**

However,  if the amount is 10 dollars, and 30 cents,  it displays as : **10.3**   (instead of :  **10.30** )

The reason is :  my program also performs arithmetical operations on the account_balance AFTER I have converted it using the "number_format" function.

For example :

```
     $correct_account_balance -= 0.25   (this will subtract 0.25 each time the program is executed)
```

This is why, anytime there is a "**zero**" at the end of the actual amount (like : 10.30), it displays as : **10.3**

Is there anyway to get around this?  Google doesn't seem to know;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reason is : my program also performs arithmetical operations on the account_balance AFTER I have converted it using the "number_format" function.

You'll need to re-run `number_format` after doing the operations on it.

You really shouldn't run it at all until it's ready for display, either, the commas it adds to larger numbers will *hugely* mess up your calculations. As an example, the following:

```
<?php

$number = 100000.30;
$number = number_format($number, 2);
$number -= 0.25;
echo number_format($number, 2);
```

results in the output:

```
99.75
```

Which means you've just stolen $99,900.55 from your customers with a type conversion error.